# Entropy conservation of binary functions

Tags: entropy, binary-operations, bit-strings

In the merge function from https://github.com/ifdefelse/ProgPOW the authors talk about **entropy maintaining** functions that operate on bit-strings.

Can someone explain what this is? I found literally nothing on the Internet so fare.

Comment: I assume that "entropy maintaining" means that if you have a transformation  $(X_1, ..., X_n) \rightarrow (Y_1, ..., Y_n)$ then $H(X_1, ..., X_n) = H(Y_1, ..., Y_n)$.  It would be true, for example, for a permutation $(X_1, X_2, X_3) \rightarrow (X_3, X_1, X_2)$. It is also true for any injective map $f:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow A$ that sends each of the $2^n$ possibilities for $(x_1, ..., x_n)$ to a unique value $f(x_1, ..., x_n) \in A$ (here, $A$ is just any set that has at least $2^n$ elements).

Comment: So $H$ is shannon entropy? How is it computed?

Comment: If $B$ is the set of all $n$ dimensional binary vectors and $p(x_1, ..., x_n) = P[(X_1,...,X_n)=(x_1,...,x_n)]$ for all $(x_1,...x_n)\in B$ then $$H(X_1, ..., X_n) = -\sum_{(x_1, ..., x_n) \in B} p(x_1, ..., x_n)\log(p(x_1, ..., x_n))$$ You can see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)

Comment: Cool thanks. You might want to copy paste it into an actual answer. Its a nice and clean def of the entropy after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comments:

#### Entropy maintaining

I assume that "entropy maintaining" refers to a map $(X_1, ..., X_n)\rightarrow (Y_1, ..., Y_n)$ with the property that: 
$$H(X_1, ..., X_n) = H(Y_1, ..., Y_n)$$

#### Definition of entropy $H(X_1, ..., X_n)$

Let $B$ be the set of all $n$ dimensional binary vectors. Define the probability mass function: 
$$p(x_1, ..., x_n) = P[(X_1,...,X_n)=(x_1,...,x_n)] \quad \forall (x_1,...x_n)\in B$$ 
Then
$$H(X_1, ..., X_n) = -\sum_{(x_1, ..., x_n) \in B} p(x_1, ..., x_n)\log(p(x_1, ..., x_n))$$ 
If the log is a natural log, the entropy is in units of *nats*.  If it is a base-2 log it is in units of *bits*. If $(X_1, ..., X_n)$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli-$(1/2)$ variables then 
$$ H(X_1, ..., X_n) = n \quad (bits)$$

You can also see here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)